# Why I cannot change static final int field with reflection from kotlin android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection

I have following java class with static final int which I need to change via reflection:

```
class DateValidator {
   public static final int DIFF = 20;
}
```

And from Android Kotlin I try to change it value from 20 to 100:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        println("@@@@DateValidator.DIFF: ${DateValidator.DIFF}")
        val clazz = DateValidator::class.java
        println("@@@clazz: $clazz")
        val field: Field = clazz.getDeclaredField("DIFF")
        println("@@@field: $field")
        println("@@@field.isAccessible: ${field.isAccessible}")
        field.isAccessible = true
        println("@@@field.isAccessible2: ${field.isAccessible}")
        val fieldAccessFlags: Field = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("accessFlags")
        println("@@@fieldAccessFlags: $fieldAccessFlags")
        println("@@@fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible: ${fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible}")
        fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible = true
        println("@@@fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible2: ${fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible}")
        fieldAccessFlags.setInt(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
        field.set(null, 100)
        println("@@@@DateValidator.DIFF2: ${DateValidator.DIFF}")
        field.setInt(null, 100)
        println("@@@@DateValidator.DIFF3: ${DateValidator.DIFF}")

    }
```

And I have following output in Logcat:

```
@@@@DateValidator.DIFF: 20
@@@clazz: class com.droiddevstar.changestaticprj.DateValidator
@@@field: public static final int com.droiddevstar.changestaticprj.DateValidator.DIFF
@@@field.isAccessible: false
@@@field.isAccessible2: true
@@@fieldAccessFlags: private int java.lang.reflect.Field.accessFlags
@@@fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible: false
@@@fieldAccessFlags.isAccessible2: true
@@@@DateValidator.DIFF2: 20
@@@@DateValidator.DIFF3: 20
```

Perhapse reflection doesn't work with primitive int?

Comment: Static final primitive variables cannot be changed.  The compiler inlines the value at all the use sites.

Answer (score 0):

**static final** is like **const val** in Kotlin, that variable can't change.

**DateValidator** class is declare **DIFF** is static. so it can't change

you can read this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-static-variable-java/)

Comment: Reflection can do that in theory, because reflection can basically do anything including ignoring `final`. It just doesn't work in practice (for [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)) because compiled code does not reference the variable anymore, the compiler copies the value that variable had at compile time into all the compiled classes that use that variable. And that code can't be changed by reflection (class loaders could in theory do even that).